# Attempt to invoke virtual method widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to put json array into recyclerview but when i run it, it gives me the
"Attempt to invoke virtual method widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager on a null object reference"

This my fragment code :

```
public class ShopsFragment extends Fragment {


private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List<ShopsData> data_List;
public ShopsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shops, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    data_List = new ArrayList<>();
    StoresBackgroundTask backgroundTask = new StoresBackgroundTask(getActivity());
    backgroundTask.execute();




    return rootView;

}
```

}

and here is my onPreExecude Code :

```
    @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) activity.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ctx);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new StoresRecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I'm getting the error at the 4th line of the onPreExecude.
what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's because you're trying to retrieve recyclerView from within a method run in a different thread. If recyclerView is a Class variable, just remove the `recyclerView = (RecyclerView) activity.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);` line from within the onPreExecute() method.

Comment: it's just a recyclerview in it